# Display unicode characters in Java Gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, unicode

I am writing a java project using gradle for school. My project is a game that involves displaying unicode emojis that represent players on JButtons and JLabels. In the file in question, the emojis properly display when I compile using `javac`, but when I `gradle run` the actual project itself they do not. I have tried searching for answer for many hours but cannot find a solution.

Comment: What is the character encoding of your Java source files (your IDE/editor should display that, and it's probably UTF8). Have you set the compiler encoding to the same value, as explained in http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2012/06/gradle-goodness-set-java-compiler.html? What does the program display instead of the emojis? Does the font used by your program support these characters? Any minimal, complete example to share?

Comment: yeah I tried setting the compiler encoding like in the link, it didn't change anything.

Comment: Then answer all of my other questions, and provide a complete minimal example reproducing the issue. It shouldn't be longer than 20 lines, code and gradle build included.